# Check the eventhandler exist for particular event present in the object

Tags: c#, events

I have use the following code snippet with in the for loop

```
DataTable childTable = dataTable.DataSet.Relations[relationName].ChildTable;

if (childTable != null)
{
   iBindingList = childTable.AsDataView() as IBindingList;
   iBindingList.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(GridDataRecord_ListChanged);
}
```

In this case I need to check the listchanged event is already invoked for iBindinglist object.Can you please look into this and provide suggestion to achieve this. Thanks in Advcance.

Regards,
Rajasekar

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to see if your handler has already been added. Luckily, you do not need to.

```
iBindingList.ListChanged -= GridDataRecord_ListChanged;
iBindingList.ListChanged += GridDataRecord_ListChanged;
```

Assuming a well-behaved class (and in this case, you should be able to trust that the class is well-behaved), you can safely remove `GridDataRecord_ListChanged` even if it has not been added. Removing it will simply do nothing. If you only ever add the handler after removing it, it will never be added multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the handler before attaching it

```
if (childTable != null)
{
   iBindingList = childTable.AsDataView() as IBindingList;
   iBindingList.ListChanged -= new ListChangedEventHandler(GridDataRecord_ListChanged);
   iBindingList.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(GridDataRecord_ListChanged);
}
```

If you're running a single thread environment and you attach this event like this all the time then it should be fine. However, if there are multiple threads there could be race conditions. As mentioned in the comments this is an issue if you have multiple threads attaching the same delegate. `-=` only removes the last delegate so multiple additions and a single removal will mean that the event is still attached.

Alternatively, have a flag that checks if the event has been subscribed to.

```
bool listChangedSubscribed = false;  
if (childTable != null)
{
   iBindingList = childTable.AsDataView() as IBindingList;
   iBindingList.ListChanged -= new ListChangedEventHandler(GridDataRecord_ListChanged);
   if(!listChangedSubscribed)
   {
       iBindingList.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(GridDataRecord_ListChanged);
       listChangedSubscribed = true; 
   }
```

Comment: Good point about multiple threads, I forgot about that in my answer. To be clear, it doesn't matter if there are multiple threads that use the same `iBindingList`, it only matters if there are multiple threads that attempt to add the exact same delegate.

Comment: +1 for the clarification. `-=` only removes the last delegate so multiple additions and a single removal will mean that the event is still attached.